# when clicked on dropdown list item call a same list item name function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

dropdown list contain 3 item namely emp name, prod info, sales status, when i clicked list item, it should call function same list item name. here i am doing when i clicked list item, item name space removing and and calling to function but it not calling. how can i do. bellow is i tried code.

```
html
----
<ul>
<li class="item">emp name</li>
<li class="item">prod info</li>
<li class="item">sale status</li>
</ul>

javascript
----------
jQuery("ul .item").click(function(){
   var x = $(this).text();
   var y = x.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        y+();
});
function empname(){
  console.log("emp");
}
function prodinfo(){
   console.log("prodinfo");
}
function salestatus(){
  console.log("salesstaus");
}
```

Comment: call like this window[y]();

Comment: i tryied but it not calling

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

```js
jQuery("ul .item").click(function() {
  var x = $(this).text();
  var y = x.replace(/\s+/g, '') +"()";
  eval(y)
});

function empname() {
  console.log("emp");
}

function prodinfo() {
  console.log("prodinfo");
}

function salestatus() {
  console.log("salesstaus");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">emp name</li>
  <li class="item">prod info</li>
  <li class="item">sale status</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
jQuery("ul .item").click(function(){
   var x = $(this).text();
   var y = x.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    //console.log(y);
    eval(y +'()');
});
function empname(){
  console.log("emp");
}
function prodinfo(){
   console.log("prodinfo");
}
function salestatus(){
 console.log("salestatus");
}
```

Comment: Dhaval, did you check the previous answer before you made yours?  there is not much point in making identical answers

Comment: No when my answer place and after refresh page and i am see ans will be already given

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Ok next time i am do as per you say

Answer (score 0):

Why should you depend on some dynamic way of calling function by processing string between html tags. The text using between the html tags are for reading purpose only. you should not process it, because incase, if you are changing the text value to somehow it will affect your coding and the code needs to be changed according to the text. and if the predefined functions are already known, you can do it in the below way.

```
<script>
function empname(){
  alert("emp");
}
function prodinfo(){
   alert("prodinfo");
}
function salestatus(){
  alert("salesstaus");
}
</script>
<ul>
  <li class="item" onclick="empname()">emp name</li>
  <li class="item" onclick="prodinfo()">prod info</li>
  <li class="item" onclick="salestatus()">sale status</li>
</ul>
```